# Assign result of dynamic SQL in Procedure A to variable defined in Procedure B

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am struggling with getting the result back for a dynamic query that is being called from a different stored procedures. Here is what I am trying to achieve.

Procedure A:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A
    @C1 int, @F1 int
AS
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT ID FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE WHERE '+@C1+' = +'@F1'
    EXEC(@SQL)
```

Procedure B:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE B
    @C1 int, @F1 int
AS
    DECLARE @Result INT
    EXEC @Result = A  @C1, @F1
```

I need to run stored procedure B and let it return back to me the result. I just cannot seem to get the correct result back. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following two store procedures query statement

Procedure A:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE A
@C1 VARCHAR(250),
@F1 int
AS
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ID FROM PatientTest WHERE '+ @C1+' = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@F1)
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Procedure B:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE B
@C1 VARCHAR(250),
@F1 int
AS
Declare @Result int
EXEC @Result = A  @C1, @F1
```

If you will face further problem, please let me know in comment. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Emdad, thanks for your response. Unfortunately this did not work. The issue seems to be that the '@SQL' is being run in a separate batch and therefore the result is not being captured from within Procedure A. Also, I see you decalred an int variable '@G1' but did not use it.

Comment: I just added @G1 and print function in test purpose. I have modified the query. Can you please let me know your current result which procedure B returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two. I think you will meet your expected result.

**Procedure 1**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetValue
@ColumnName VARCHAR(250),
@ColumnValue VARCHAR(250)
AS
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = 'SELECT Email FROM Person WHERE '+ @ColumnName + ' = ''' + @ColumnValue + ''''
EXEC (@SQL)
-- EXEC GetValue 'MobileNo', '+8801919111333'
```

**Procedure 2**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReturnValue
@ColumnName VARCHAR(250),
@ColumnValue VARCHAR(250)
AS
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(250)
EXEC @Result = GetValue @ColumnName, @ColumnValue
-- EXEC ReturnValue 'MobileNo', '+8801919111333'
```